# flutter Error: The argument type 'ContentType' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I got an error when I run my App:

> Error: The argument type 'ContentType' can't be assigned to the
>   parameter type 'String'.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

```
Response res = await dio.post(ocrUrl,data:{"image":base64Image}, options: new Options(contentType:ContentType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")));
```

Comment: Can you give some more context around where your code resides. This will make it easier for others to help solve the problem.

Comment: To build on @FabiandePabian's request, it'd be useful to include your code in the question directly, instead of linking to a screenshot. Code in screenshots is difficult to copy and paste in order to reproduce a question or—more likely in this case—paste into an answer alongside corrections. It's much easier, and less error prone, for you to copy and paste this code than it will be for contributors to transcribe from your screenshot. Do you mind editing that into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ContentType.parse
```

Does not return a string, but you need a string for the options parameter.

Do like so:

```
"Content-Type":"application/whatever"
```

or

```
options: Options(contentType: ContentType.whatever)
```

instead of parse.